# How to use use docker-compose and dockerfile to run commands on a volume?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, composer-php

I am trying to setup docker-compose that run php, composer and mysql stack.

I have this following docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  provision:
    container_name: 'docker_stack'
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - ./.conf/:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
```

And in my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache


RUN a2enmod rewrite

RUN service apache2 restart

WORKDIR /var/www/html/
RUN php init --env="Development" --overwrite=All
```

However the last command fails because it cannot find the init file which is a php script.

And also how do i attach composer to it?

Answer (score 0):

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends git zip

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN composer --version
```

Is what I'm using in my Dockerfiles to install composer.

Also, did you try using

```
RUN php /var/www/html/init --env="Development" --overwrite=All
```

Comment: Yes i tried using /var/www/html/init. but i still get the error Could not open input file: /var/www/html/init. Is it because it's on a volume?

Comment: Is there anything in your folder? According to your Dockerfile, there should be the Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml

Comment: Use the following: "docker ps" to get the ID of your container. Then "docker exec -it ID bash" to connect to your container. "ls /var/www/html" - What is the output? If it is empty, your volume sharing isn't working properly.

Comment: Yes there are files when i ls in the container

Comment: Is 'init' the filename? Not init.php? Just making sure we debug it correctly.